# Sitecore: Saving changes to a "form", based on a master template

Tags: forms, security, sitecore, structure, roles

In Sitecore, how could one go about creating following solution:

- We need to a have a master "form" that is administered from the "headquarter" eg. a SC admin account builds and maintains it.
- A "copy" of this master form should should be accessible by some users/roles, and their choices/selections/input/etc on this form, should be saved for each of the users/roles one submitted.

If it could be build with the use of Web Forms for Marketers, that would be a plus.

Comment: Are you talking about purely managing the form fields in the CMS, or is your second bullet about the front-end submission of the form?

Comment: Yes, the second bullet is submission is from the frontend, activated by extranet users.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are met exactly with the use of the Web Forms for Marketers module:

- [Download the module on the SDN here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Sitecore%206/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%20Module.aspx)
- Refer to the [user guide (PDF link)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_3%20user%20guide-usletter.pdf) and [reference doc (PDF link)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_3%20reference-usletter.pdf) to understand how to create "master" forms in the Sitecore admin and how front-end users fill those forms in